# datagrid cannot be found

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I create each datagrid to be added to the NavigatorConent(), however, how do I retrieve the datagrid by ID so that I can point the ArrayCollection to datagrid's dataprovider?

```
private var pdg:String;
    private function stabAdd():void {
                var dg1:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
                var cn:NavigatorContent = new NavigatorContent(); 
                stab.addElement(cn);
                cn.name = "nc"+nu;
                dg1.id = "nc"+nu;
                pdg = dg1.id;
                dg1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,cc);
                nu++;
```

This will throw an error which pdg cannot be found, I wonder why:

```
trace(DataGrid(pdg));
```

Comment: Why are you trying to give a component an ID (or name) dynamically?  What purpose will that serve?  Where does the trace statement show up in relation to the rest of your code?  When is that method called?  What exactly is the stab variable?  Are you using the Spark DataGrid or MX DataGrid? Which version of the Flex SDK are you using? What purpose does nu++ serve if you aren't in a loop?

Comment: pdg is a String, and you're trying to convert it to a DataGrid.  Error.  Amongst that, there's a lot of bad coding practices going on, most of which Flextras already mentioned.

Comment: I see, so do you suggest using multiple AC for one datagrid? I'm using tabnavigator that will have datagrid in each navigator contents. Flex 4 and using mx:datagrid. The purpose of nu++ is to assign a unique name (dg1, dg2, etc) to each datagrid so that I can assign AC to that datagrid's dataprovider

Answer (score 1):

> The purpose of nu++ is to assign a
>   unique name (dg1, dg2, etc) to each
>   datagrid so that I can assign AC to
>   that datagrid's dataprovider

I can respect the need to give every component a unique name.  The appropriate way to do that in ActionScript is not to specify the id/name field of the component, but rather to create an instance of the component as a variable.  Something like this:

```
protected var myGrid : DataGrid;
```

And you can now access myGrid anywhere in the component, or in it's children, without creating some complicated scheme.  If you need multiple DataGrid's you can store them in an array:

```
protected var myGridArray : Array = new Array();
```

And somewhere later in your code--probably createChildren() do something like this:

```
loop
 var newGrid : DataGrid = new DataGrid()
 myGridArray.push(newGrid);
end loop
```

For the most part, this is how all the Flex list based components do it with itemRenderers.  They have an array of visible renderers.

As stated in @J_A_X_ comments, you are trying to convert pdg--a string--into a DataGrid.  I would expect that to return a null value, as Flex casts tend to fail quietly.

If you want more help, you'll have to tell us the explicit error that you're receiving, possibly with line numbers and more code.